# Выводить данные с БД mysql на график (библиотека D3)

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

Есть база данных и впринципе сами графики но вот проблема, я не понимаю как их связать между собой чтоб данные которые постоянно обновляются в базе данных выводились в графиках . *Очень нужна помощь*

**вот сам график**

```
    <div id="gistogram1">
  <svg></svg>
</div>

<script>

nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d.label })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value })
            .staggerLabels(true)
            //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
            .showValues(true)
            .duration(250)
            ;

        d3.select('#gistogram1 svg')
            .datum(historicalBarChart)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });

</script>

<script>
 historicalBarChart = [
        {
            key: "Cumulative Return",
            values: [
                {
                    "label" : "A" ,
                    "value" : 29.765957771107
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "B" ,
                    "value" : 0
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "C" ,
                    "value" : 32.807804682612
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "D" ,
                    "value" : 196.45946739256
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "E" ,
                    "value" : 0.19434030906893
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "F" ,
                    "value" : 98.079782601442
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "G" ,
                    "value" : 13.925743130903
                } ,
                {
                    "label" : "H" ,
                    "value" : 5.1387322875705
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
</script>
```

**база данных**

```
<?php
    $username = "web_user" 
    $password = "Gf45Rn27G";   
    $host = 192.168.0.38,1435;
    $database="plc_server_exp";

    $server = sql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    $connection = sql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "
    query here
    ";

    $query = sql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    sql_close($server);
?>
```

Comment: Что выводит php скрипт?

Comment: Ничего,это просто подключение к бд и массив в который потом как-то можно вставить данные из таблицы

Comment: echo json_encode($data); // эта строка выводит данные, что она выводит?

Comment: То что потом будет в массиве ,то есть строки с данными в формате json

Comment: Ты есть в скайпе ? Добавься если есть ,там поговорим как раз metallist77788

Comment: Чтобы показать данные надо преобразовать их в данные которые поймет библиотека которая строит график. Пример этих данных есть в приведенном коде js. А что получается на выходе php непонятно. Я есть в скайпе, но у меня нет времени на длинные разговоры. Повторяю еще раз, покажи что что выводит php и возможно получишь помощь.

Comment: Если это делается один раз, то вот эта php могла бы на выходе давать прямо вот тот html что сверху, с впечатанными в него данными. Если же требуется периодическое обновление данных на клиенте, то вам надо вызывать вашу php через ajax метод, по приходу данных скармливать из d3